# How to debug/fix a router that shows no sign of life?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

**Context:** a previous employer gave me a Linksys *WRT54G2* when they went out of business a few years ago. It was already an old router back then, so I never bothered using it until now - I'm trying to build a networking lab for learning purposes. I remember he mentioning that the router was working when he handed it to me.

**Problem:** when I turn the router on, most of the lights flash for a second, but that's about it. After that I get no visual response from the router. Needless to say I can't connect to it either by ethernet or wi-fi.

I opened the box to see if there was anything strange, maybe some piece missing or wires disconnected, but everything looks fine.

I'm hoping this is not a hardware thing (definitely not my forte), but at the same time I don't even know where to start in order to identify the problem.

So, in generic terms, the question is: given a router that doesn't connect to any devices through wi-fi or ethernet, how should I proceed in identifying the issue?

Comment: honestly, these days it would be more use as a door-stop. I wouldn't bother. It's certainly not worth giving to any technician to try fix - his bill for opening the case would be more than the unit is worth.

Comment: Test the mains adapter with a voltmeter. The adapter usually is one of the cheapest made parts, they break down quite often. And it's easy to mix them up with other adapters with the same connector, but different voltage.